# Where to store sensitive data for a Blazor Hybrid project?

Tags: blazor, blazor-hybrid

I'm making an app that uses both Blazor Hybrid and Blazor Server apps with one set of Razor UI components shared across the different platforms.

I learned that it's a bad idea to directly call an external database (SQL Server) in a Blazor Hybrid app. If it does, the connection string would be exposed because the app's code is downloaded to the user's machine. This is a security risk. In fact, the Android platform doesn't even let me make a direct call, throwing `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform.`

The issue is not present with a Blazor Server app as the code is never downloaded and instead the page is streamed to the user's machine. So, I can safely store any sensitive data in `appsettings.js` configuration file.

After some research, I understood that the solution is to communicate with the database through an API. However, how would I safely store the credentials for authorizing communication with the API? It feels like the problem remains - sensitive API credentials appearing somewhere in the code.

Comment: You haven't to save the authorization credentials in the API. You just call the API, and it uses the provided credential from an authorization file such as `appsettings ` on the server, However, if you'd like to save sensitive data in MAUI you can use the `Secure storage`. for more info you can refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/secure-storage?view=net-maui-7.0&tabs=windows

Comment: @AlirezaK Thanks for your suggestions but I'm afraid both of them are problematic due to the possibility of users decompiling the app. If the app communicates with an `appsettings` file on the server, the communication would require authorization so users couldn't retrieve the values for themselves. I can't store them in the app. As for `Secure storage` solution, it's a great for retrieving a secret value, but how would I securely store the value for the app? I can't write a line of code in the app to store the value because that would expose it.

Comment: You're Welcome, You should store server related data such as connection string on a server that you can control and read the sensitive value from this server. You never store server related value on the user device.

Comment: The best resource I found: https://thedotnetshow.com/ - See Episode 24, entitled "Calling Secured APIs with MSAL Auth in MAUI".

Comment: I like that video. I think this would work for the specific API problem I have. But there are also other type of values I'd like to be securely stored. Maybe there is no solution to this because then I'd be able to call a database directly as I wouldn't need to worry about the connection string being found.